# Cache Raster tiles with Varnish

Tags: tiles, cache

I am trying to cache my raster tiles from Tileserver-GL. This is my actual link of tiles

[http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080/styles/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png](http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080/styles/map/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png)
(Each tile link will look like http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080/styles/map/1/1/1.png)

I have to change the `default.vlc` file to

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}
```

Now I am getting the tiles from the following link

[http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:6081/styles/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png](http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:6081/styles/map/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png)
(Each tile link will look like
http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:6081/styles/map/1/1/1.png)

When I am doing my first map load varnish is calling the tiles from the Tileserver-GL server. But the problem, it is still calling the tiles from the Tileserver-GL server. That means there were no cache png files stored.

Here is an example of how OpenStreetMap is caching there tiles. They have 3 layers but in my case I have only one layer.

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Varnish_setup

Comment: Sorry that I am of no help for your problem. I was just wondering if you know it it's also possible to serve the tiles as jpg? As that would greatly reduce the size needed for Varnish to cache?

Comment: @Georg, probably possible but I never heard anyone is using `jpg`